# Find all URLs that do not start with "http" in ElasticSearch regex 1.7

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm writing ElasticSearch (v 1.7) query to find all urls that do not start with http. But my mapping results with an empty result (while I definitely have urls not starting with http). Could you help me to fix it?

```
"query": {
  "regexp":{
    "url": {
      "value": "@&~(http.+)",
      "flags" : "ANYSTRING"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `"flags" : "ALL"` or remove `"flags" : "ANYSTRING"` without adding anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work once you remove the `flags`:

```
"query": {
  "regexp":{
    "url": {
      "value": "@&~(http.+)",
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you use `ALL` (default) as `flags` value:

```
"query": {
  "regexp":{
    "url": {
      "value": "@&~(http.+)",
      "flags" : "ALL"
    }
  }
}
```

`ANYSTRING` only enables the `@` operator, while `~` is enabled with the `COMPLEMENT` flag, and `&` operator is enabled with the `INTERSECTION` flag. Basically, it is safer to go with the default value.